# Debian mail server

Tags: php, email, debian

I am running a Debian server and have mysql set up for other projects.
I want to be able to send emails by using php that will either send from my server or even just send using a gmail accounts credentials.

I have seen some mail servers but they all seem to need to be installed on a fresh install of the server.

I have tried:

```
$recipient = $_POST["recipient"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$body =  $_POST["body"];
$headers = 'From: admin@website.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: admin@websiteh.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$sendMail = mail($recipient, $title, $body, $headers);

if( $sendMail == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your question is.

I assume that you have checked the $_POST values and don't easily trust the user input?

Your PHP Code looks good.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php

- The default Debian installation comes with the Exim Mailserver installed.
  Try a "lsof -i" or a "tail -f /var/log/mail.log"
  The first command will show you if you have something listenting on port 25 (and all the other ports). 
  The second command: "Instead of just displaying the last few lines and exiting, tail displays the lines and then monitors the file." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29)
- I would recommend to use postfix.
  (aptitude install postfix) You will find lots of help and information on the net. It is easy to setup on debian.